# Revision tab not appearing

Tags: 8, caching, nodes

I have just starting using Drupal today and am going through a tutorial for Drupal 7 (I am using Drupal 8). I have made several revisions; however, the `Revision` tab does not appear when in the `Edit` area. I am logged in as Admin and have permissions for everything. After several revisions I got fed up and decided to delete the node (content) by clicking the `Delete` tab - to my surprise, the `Revisions` tab then appeared to the right of the `Delete` tab. I cannot find any documentation on the `Revisions` tab only appearing once the delete button has been clicked. Is this standard behaviour or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a Drupal bug being actively worked on.  Once this patch is committed, the question will be of little use to further readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug, and is being fixed: https://www.drupal.org/node/2592325. The fix is already present, it just needs test coverage now.

Comment: Amazing - it's now working! Well found. **Edit**: it works on previously revised and faux deleted node sections only.

Comment: If there's something not yet fully working with that patch, please leave a comment on that issue. Thanks!

Comment: maybe i am little bit late asking for this. But i have a drupal 7 project and is not working :/

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a caching problem, possibly the revisions tab is missing cacheability information. It's dynamically shown based on whether there are revisions or not. Which means it needs to be invalidated in case the node changes.

You should open a bug report for core.